# Save color from ColorDialog and load it into labels

Tags: delphi

I'm developing the Tic Tac Toe game with an internet connection for check worldwide scores. I've also added a `ColorDialog` so the user can choose his own color for `X` and `O` inside the grid. Look at these 2 picture as example:

1. [pic1](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/280/lgt4cdd.png)
2. [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG0vb.png)

I thought to add this feature: when the user clicks Edit and then Grid item colors (from the TMenu above), a `MessageDialog` appears asking if next time you run the program, you want use this color again or the default (black). I wrote the following code:

```
procedure TfrMain.MenuItem10Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if (MessageDlg('Set this color as default? Next time you play or you open the program, you will use this color. [Yes=OK||Cancel=NO]',
   mtConfirmation,mbOKCancel,0) = mrCancel) then
   begin
    if ColorDialog1.Execute then
      for i:= 0 to 8 do
      begin
       (FindComponent('lblcell'+IntToStr(i)) as TLabel).Font.Color := ColorDialog1.Color;
      end;
    end
  else
    begin
     //saves the color somewhere, when the program will run again, it will load this color
    end;
end;
```

If you press `Cancel` the ColorDialog appears and it sets the color. My problem is that I don't know how to save the selected color and load it when the program will run again. This program also saves its stuff in a folder at `C:\tictactoe8`, so I thought to save here a text file with the color settings and load them via OnCreate event of TForm1. By the way, I don't really know how to do this, could you give me some advices?

Comment: Have you used `TRegistry` before, or are you familiar with using the Windows registry? I would recommend saving the settings as Windows registry values for your application.

Comment: An other attempt could be an IniFile http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inifile+delphi

Comment: It looks like your question is about tic tac toe, or about a colordialog, but it's neither. It's actually about storing (any) program setting. If you approach the problem that way, it will be easier for you to solve it, and easier to find information about it as well. "Storing tic tac toe colors" will probably yield less (relevant) search results than "Storing application settings". 
The latter will probably advise you to use `TRegistry` or `TiniFile`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to save the main form state of a form to the registry in Delphi. You can use this technique to save the color as well. The `KN_xxx` constants are my registry entry names. You could just call yours `Color` as the parameter name. And `KEY_SETTINGS` is your app's registry path, e.g.,  `\Software\MyCompany\TicTacToe\Settings`.

This saves the information when the form (window) is created:

```
procedure TFormTicTacToe.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  reg: TRegistry;
  idx: Integer;
begin
  reg := TRegistry.Create;

  try
    idx := RegReadInteger( reg, KN_CFPPI, 0 );

    if idx = PixelsPerInch then
    begin
      Width := RegReadInteger( reg, KN_CFWIDTH, Width );
      Height := RegReadInteger( reg, KN_CFHEIGHT, Height );
      Left := RegReadInteger( reg, KN_CFLEFT, Left );
      Top := RegReadInteger( reg, KN_CFTOP, Top );
    end;

    WindowState := TWindowState( RegReadInteger(reg, KN_CFWINDOWSTATE, Integer(wsNormal)) );
  finally
    reg.CloseKey;
    reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And here we save it as the form closes:

```
procedure TFormTicTacToe.FormClose(Sender: TObject;
  var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
  reg := TRegistry.Create;

  if not reg.OpenKey(KEY_SETTINGS, true) then
  begin
    reg.Free;
    Exit;
  end;

  with reg do try
    if WindowState = wsNormal then
    begin
      WriteInteger( KN_CFWIDTH, Width );
      WriteInteger( KN_CFHEIGHT, Height );
      WriteInteger( KN_CFLEFT, Left );
      WriteInteger( KN_CFTOP, Top );
    end;

    WriteInteger( KN_CFPPI, PixelsPerInch );
  finally
    CloseKey;
    Free;
  end;  { with reg do try }
end;
```

In your case, you just need to save and retrieve the color.

Comment: Here I save my settings in a registry. Is it somewhere in C: ? Thank you by the way! :)

Comment: The registry is the Windows registry. Maintained by Windows. It's the most standard way to save application config data in Windows since `Windows 95` came out.

Comment: In my opinion a .ini file is preferable, and this should be stored in the user's appdata folder.

Comment: For something like saving a color setting, it probably doesn't make a huge difference either way. Delphi has a class `TIniFile` for using INI files if the OP chooses that route. Here's an example explanation: http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/tinifile.htm.